# Android Library: Loading Autocad 3D files in android

Tags: android, autocad, dwg, walkthrough

I want to load AutoCAD 3d objects into my Android project,
is there any library available for android ?

Comment: This is what I found when I searched for an open source library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169390/open-source-cad-drawing-dwg-library-in-c-sharp

Comment: Might be sure this will help 
https://github.com/ADN-DevTech/Autodesk-ReCap-Samples/tree/master/Android

http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/net/page/4/

adndevblog.typepad.com/files/edandroidclient.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to show AutoCAD 3D models, you can use the WebGL viewer, see at http://developer.autodesk.com for documentation and keys